# How can I filter and sort on a computed value via Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-sql, wcf-ria-services

I have the following table structure:

```
Table Item
Id, ExpectedCost, ExpectedQuantity, ...

Table Scan
Id, ItemId, ActualCost, ActualQuantity, ...
```

Where `ItemId` is a foreign key into the `Item` table. This gives a 1 to many relationship between `Item` and `Scan`.

This is translated to C# to give the following classes which are autogenerated:

```
class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal ExpectedCost { get; set; }
    public decimal ExpectedQuantity { get; set; }
    public EntitySet<Scan> Scans { get; set; }
}

class Scan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public EntityRef<Item> Item { get; set; }
    public decimal ActualCost { get; set; }
    public decimal ActualQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to extend the `Item` class to get the discrepancy between the expected and actual values:

```
public partial class Item
{
    public decimal ActualCost
    {
        get { return Scans.Sum(s => s.ActualCost); }
    }

    public decimal CostDiscrepancy
    {
        get { return ActualCost - ExpectedCost; }
    }
}
```

The data is read from the database using Linq To SQL and passed back to a Silverlight client via WCF RIA Services. It's displayed on a data grid. The calculation works as the actual cost and the discrepancy values are displayed on the grid.

The problem I have is that when I try to sort or filter on the calculated columns I get the following error:

> Message : Load operation failed for query 'GetItems'. The member 'Item.ActualCost' has no supported translation to SQL.

I've tweaked the `ActualCost` method, but as long as it calls the `Sum` Linq extension method I get this error.

What can I do to get the calculated value(s) and allow sorting and filtering on those values?

Comment: Create a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table) in the database and map it into your POCO. Linq-to-SQL can't translate arbitrary code into SQL.

Comment: @spender - interesting read. The only issue is that we're running on SQL 2012 R2 at the moment.

Comment: Hmm. Strange requirements for that document. I'm pretty certain that CCs are supported in 2012r2.

Comment: @spender - yeah. I've just found that out myself. Looks like it might be a viable solution.

Comment: IIRC You'll probably need the column to call out to a user-defined function as it's counting children in another table.